# Tridion cannot find my resources

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

I want to add my own resources to my current GUI extension project. To do this I was following [Bart Koopman's example](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/ui-extension-localization). However when I add my resources Tridion just wont show the DasboardView and give a syntax error.

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "AssemblyName.FolderName.FileName.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AssemblyName" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsLocalizationResources.BuildCustomResources(StringBuilder sb)
at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsLocalizationResources.get_Contents()
at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsLocalizationResources.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, List`1 writtenResources)
at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsLocalizationResources.WriteContents(HttpResponse response)
at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Http.LocalizationStringsProvider.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

---

What i have done is:

Added the following to the configuration file:

```
<localization>
  <cfg:clientresource clientname="MyResourceName" servertype="AssemblyName.FolderName.FileName, ContentManager.GUI.Extensions" />
</localization>
```

Build the project and moved the .resx files (FileName.resx, FileName.nl.resx, FileName.fr.resx, FileName.de.resx) to ..\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\App_GlobalResources\

---

But now I am stuck at where my error is. One thing that can be important is that my custom editor is located in a Virtual Folder (But everything until these resources worked with that Virtual Folder).

Any sugestions to where I have to look?

Comment: did you literally put in your configuration "AssemblyName.FolderName.FileName" or is this just as an example ? I believe this should be the actual namespace of the resources in your project

Comment: Next to that, did you also place the dll of your project in the tridion bin folder (Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin) ?

Comment: Thanks! I indeed did nog move the .dll of the project to the right folder. Thank you, I was searching ons this for couple of hours!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, next to defining the resources files in the configuration, you should also move the dll of your GUI extension project to the Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin folder.

I put this answer in here for clarity, so this question can have an "accepted" answer.

Comment: Just to be clear: the resources should also be embedded in that DLL (and you should copy any satellite assemblies you have for other languages too).